# material ui next dialog textfield underline color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the underline color of a textfield inside a dialog with my secondary palette color? I couldn't do it since the documentation it's quite confusing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using material-ui-next, you can use **overrides** in **createMuiTheme**.

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:before': { //underline color when textfield is inactive
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        '&:hover:not($disabled):before': { //underline color when hovered 
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

});

Then wrap you app with **MuiThemeProvider**

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Root />
 </MuiThemeProvider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It will overwrite underline color of all TextField material-ui components. If you need to change color only for one TextField, use https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#1-specific-variation-for-a-one-time-situation

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out how to do it but this one is cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Rinat's answer doesn't seem to work on the current version, v16.13.1.  A slight change is needed to use `borderBottom` rather than `backgroundColor`.

(borrowing his answer to make the answer clearer, hopefully I haven't broken any SO guidelines)

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:before': { //underline color when textfield is inactive
          borderBottom: `1px solid ${"red"}`,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        },
        '&:hover:not($disabled):before': { //underline color when hovered 
          borderBottom: `2px solid ${"red"}`,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        },
      }
  }
}
```

And wrap it with MuiThemeProvider just like before:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";

ReactDOM.render(
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Root />
 </MuiThemeProvider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```