# material ui next textfield underline color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is an answer that worked for the last version: [material ui next dialog textfield underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489252/material-ui-next-dialog-textfield-underline-color?rq=1)

Since the version 1 of material ui is out this config doesn't work for me anymore. The on hover part has no effect any more:

```
'&:hover:not($disabled):before': { //underline color when hovered 
    backgroundColor: 'green',
},
```

Has anyone already figured out how to do it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my project (I'm using @material-ui/core: "1.4.3"), and i found this solution in order to fix this issue.

1) First import MuiThemeProvider & createMuiTheme on your component:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

2) Then Add this lines of code after your imports:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  // For Underline Color After Click
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#00BCD6"},
  },
  // For Underline Hover Color
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:hover:not($disabled):not($error):not($focused):before': {
          borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42)',
        },
      },
    }
  }
});
```

3) And for the final step, wrap your component that you want to edit with this code:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>

// Your Component here

</MuiThemeProvider>
```

I Hope this helps you! :)